# How do you write to a log file in Clojure, using core.async?

Tags: logging, asynchronous, clojure, java-io, core.async

I want to use core.async as a logger that writes out to a file, so I created a test.txt file, stuck it in my resources folder and wrote this code:

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(use 'clojure.core.async)

(def print-chan (chan))

(go (loop []
      (when-let [v (<! print-chan)]
        (with-open [wrtr (writer "resources/test.txt" :append true)]
          (.write wrtr v))
        (recur)))) 

(>!! print-chan 42)
```

When I run this, however, I find that it will only replace what is in the file, and not append to it. Also, sometimes the output that is written to the file is odd. Once, I tried to put 42 and I got * instead. When I use the writer without the core.async functions, it works as expected. What is the idiomatic way to write to a log file in Clojure using core.async? Thanks in advance!

*I am using light table.

Answer (score 4):

`wrtr` is a [java.io.BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

When you send `42` (long) into the channel, you're calling `(.write wrtr 42)` which invokes this method:

```
write(int c)
Writes a single character.
```

`42` represents the `\*` character on the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) so that's what's being written.

Instead, you want to invoke this Writer method via `(.write wrtr "42")`:

```
write(String str)
Writes a string.
```

And you can do that by converting the values read from the channel into strings:

```
(.write wrtr (str v))
```

Comment: Thanks for this super simple and helpful answer. The only problem I have now is getting it to print each item to a new line. Should I look in the Clojure or Java documentation to figure this out?

Comment: Just write a `newline` after your log line. Either include it in the message: `(.write wrtr "42\n")`, or write it explicitly: `(.write wrtr "\n")`.

Comment: Exactly. Just change the line to `(.write wrtr (str v "\n"))`.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the file anew in each loop/recur cycle, this is why it's not appending.

What you need to do is open the writer *once* for the life of the program.

```
(go
  (with-open [wrtr (writer "resources/test.txt" :append true)]
    (loop []
      (when-let [v (<! print-chan)]
        (.write wrtr (str v "\n"))
      (recur))))
```

I just had to write code like this today. What I found was that you have to call `with-open` inside the goroutine. Because of this (I assume), you can't use the `with-open` macro with the `go-loop` macro.